# Symfony 2.8 redirect to extenalURL with post data

Tags: php, symfony

How can i redirect a user to my client shop system and send POST login data to our client Shop system.

This is what the form looks like however its not secure as anybody can read the username and password

```
<form action="http://externalUrl/login.php" method="post" name="ExtLogin" target="_blank">
 <input name="extlogin" value="1" type="hidden">
 <input name="custno" value="11111" type="hidden">
 <input name="custappno" value="1" type="hidden">
 <input name="pwd" value="111111" type="hidden">
 <button type="submit" href="#">Client Shop</button>
```

New Code:

shop.html.twig:

```
<a href="{{ path('forward_shop') }}" target="_blank"><input type="Submit" value="Go to shop" /></a>
```

ShopController.php

```
public function ShopAction(){ 
  return $this->redirect('http://externalUrl/login.php');
}
```

How do i redirect to the URL along with the post data, if such request cannot be made is there any alternative?

Comment: You should `curl` in these cases. It will send the values to your 3rd party website without exposing your data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use BuzzBundle (https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioBuzzBundle), a simple bundle for making http requests.